# Oozie job not present in job list

Tags: oozie-coordinator

I have an Oozie job, which I can see using the `oozie jobs -filter` command :

```
oozie jobs -filter name="SparkMyJobCoordinator" -jobtype coord
```

That returns :

```
#bla bla bla oozie config
Job ID                                   App Name       Status    Freq Unit         Started                 Next Materialized
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001951-180518111214886-oozie-oozi-C     SparkMyJobCoordinatorRUNNING   1    DAY          2018-05-29 01:00 GMT    2018-05-30 01:00 GMT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However I do not see this job when trying to print all my jobs. I see some jobs, including one supposed to launch a Hive command, but not the "Spark" one.

```
oozie jobs -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -jobtype coord
```

That returns:

```
#bla bla bla oozie onfig
#bla bla bla some other jobs
Job ID                                   App Name       Status    Freq Unit         Started                 Next Materialized
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0002106-180518111214886-oozie-oozi-C     HiveMyJobCoordinatorRUNNING   1    DAY          2018-05-30 01:00 GMT    2018-05-31 01:00 GMT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#bla bla bla some other jobs
```

The only difference that I see between these two jobs are that this one is in a WAITING state. Why is this job not listed in the last command?

Comment: RTFM: by default the Oozie CLI sets a cut-off at 100 entries when sending the REST request. Override with e.g. `-len 20000` and also set a `-filter ***` on job status/owner/etc to avoid collecting too much junk.

Comment: Yep, that's it. You can write this comment as an answer so I can accept it and mark this question as resolved.